# Check multiple var if exists in array with grep

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, conditional-statements

I am using this code to check one $var if exists in array :

```
 if echo ${myArr[@]} | grep -qw $myVar; then echo "Var exists on array" fi
```

How could I combine more than one $vars to my check? Something like grep -qw $var1,$var2; then ... fi

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if echo ${myArr[@]} | grep -qw -e "$myVar" -e "$otherVar"
then 
  echo "Var exists on array"
fi
```

From the man-page:

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>                Use PATTERN as the pattern. 
>   This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-). (-e is specified by POSIX.)

But if you want to use arrays like this you might as well use the bash built-in [associative arrays](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays).

To implement and logic:

```
myVar1=home1
myVar2=home2

myArr[0]=home1
myArr[1]=home2
if echo ${myArr[@]} | grep -qw -e "$myVar1.*$myVar2" -e "$myVar2.*$myVar1"
then 
          echo "Var exists on array"
fi

# using associative arrays

declare -A assoc
assoc[home1]=1
assoc[home2]=1

if [[ ${assoc[$myVar1]} && ${assoc[$myVar2]} ]]; then
  echo "Var exists on array"
fi
```

Comment: Could be simplified like this: `egrep -qw "$myVar|$otherVar"`

Comment: This code is very close, but what if i want to make a conditional &&?  myVar && otherVar (both must exists in Array) then "ok" else "not ok" ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need `grep` for this, Bash is perfectly capable of doing Extended Regular Expressions itself (Bash 3.0 or later).

```
pattern="$var1|$var2|$var3"

for element in "${myArr[@]}"
do
    if [[ $element =~ $pattern ]]
    then
        echo "$pattern exists in array"
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something quadratic, but aware of spaces:

```
myArr=(aa "bb c" ddd)

has_values(){ 
  for e in "${myArr[@]}" ; do
    for f ; do
      if [ "$e" = "$f" ]; then return 0 ; fi
    done
  done 
  return 1
}

if has_values "ee" "bb  c" ; then echo yes ; else echo "no" ; fi
```

this example will print no because `"bb  c" != "bb c"`

Comment: This doesn't do regular expression matching, though.